Docker error: "cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists" when running Strapi image
I was given a strapi.tar file containing a Docker image for Strapi that is supposed to work in production. I loaded it using the command:
docker load < strapi.tar

This worked, and I can see the image. However, when I try to run the image with:
docker run strapi/strapi:pm2

I get this error:
docker: Error response from daemon: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b9b3df6c148e96163e71a57824581e9f3b0076ae9427dd7c2acbb0cc6f4fb77b/merged/tmp/README.md.

I’m using Windows and running the commands in a Bash terminal. I also tried running it through Docker Desktop, but the same error occurs.
Does anyone know what might be causing this and how I can resolve it?
I’ve also tried clearing all images and containers to ensure there were no conflicts, but the issue persists.
